# How to update other folder other than mine in a branch

Tags: git

I am pretty new to GIT, say I create a branch to develop my feature in a sub folder inside the whole team folder, I wonder each time when I try to update others work folder in my branch(the same thing like SVN update in Git), how should I do that? Do a merge everyday?

Comment: If you are the only one operating in this folder, there is nothing to update.

Comment: @matt No it is a team, should I merge from master branch each time I start add more things? Like `git fetch --all` then `git merge master` before I start working on my stuff?

Comment: @Kuan Not necessarily. Unless you see the master having some changes in the same files you're working on, you can keep developing in your own branch

Comment: I suspect you're viewing the system in a way that is totally at odds with Git's view. In Git's mind (such as it is), a repository belongs to one and *only* one person. If seven people are working on a project, the seven people have seven repositories. Often there's an eighth "central server" repository, which these days is often on GitHub, that the seven use to share work with each other, but that part is up to you: Git just decrees that the seven people have one private instrument each. (Seven maids with seven mops? http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'm imagining that you are using the usual arrangement where there is a central repository somewhere, and you are pushing to and pulling from that central repository.

In that case, git imposes a very simple rule. You will not be able to push to the central repository if changes have been made there by others, until you pull (fetch and merge).

So, it's very easy. Keep working and committing on your own. When you are ready to share, make sure you are committed, then pull, then push (assuming the pull didn't cause any merge conflicts, which presumably it will not).

Comment: thansk, say I am working in a branch called newfeature(I also have master in my local),  when I finish committing to my local and ready to push. Should I go to my local master then pull, then switch to newfeature, do merge master then push my new feature to remote newfeature branch?

Comment: You might be overthinking this. You don't need to change branches merely in order to pull.

Comment: So you mean when I run git pull, it will auto update all my local branches with **according** remote branches? What do I do if I want to merge my newfeature to master And how do I know if there is conflict update been added to master if I keep working on newfeature branche?

Comment: "it will auto update all my local branches with according remote branches" Exactly. Do you know how git works? You have a tracking branch corresponding to each remote branch. So that gets updated (`fetch`) and merged into the corresponding local branch (`merge`), and that is what `pull` means. — Now, of course you can then look to see whether new stuff came in on the master branch. And if you _want_ to adopt the master branch changes, you can merge them into your branch. But if there is going to be a conflict, don't worry, you'll find out about that when you merge into the master branch.